# Order query results by part od column text

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I have following query:

```
SELECT t.*, c.alias as calias FROM jos2_tabs t
        JOIN jos2_tabs_category c on c.id=t.category_id
        WHERE (category_id = 43
                    OR category_id in (select id from jos2_tabs_category WHERE parentid = 43)
                    ) AND state=1 
        ORDER BY ordering2
```

And it's working as expected. But in "tabs" table I have got column "terms" which contains dates in text format (each in new line). Example:

```
18.05.2013-21.07.2013
22.05.2013-20.06.2013
01.06.2013-25.08.2013
15.06.2013-25.08.2013
06.07.2013-29.09.2013
20.07.2013-29.09.2013
17.08.2013-10.11.2013
31.08.2013-10.11.2013
03.09.2013-30.09.2013
```

What I have to do, is to modify query to order elements by dates in "terms" column. So I want to get rows which are closest to present time (can be only first row (first date). Any ideas how can I achieve this?

I need to split first row in cell "terms" to from->to pairs and then sort all rows by "from dates"

Comment: why would u store a date as string, if you store by datetime(timestamp), or use int (and separate date from time), ul get better results(efficiany wise), and your problem would disappear as well.

Comment: looks like you have 2 dates as a range in a varchar column, correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mix Order by with [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) and [SUBSTR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)

How to use:

```
SELECT t.*, c.alias as calias FROM jos2_tabs t
JOIN jos2_tabs_category c on c.id=t.category_id
WHERE (category_id = 43
            OR category_id in (select id from jos2_tabs_category WHERE parentid = 43)
            ) AND state=1 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTR(terms, 0, 10),'%d.%m.%Y') ASC
```

Comment: It works! Thank You. Do You know how can I limit results to only contain dates >NOW?

Comment: you can use this function with `HAVING` for example `HAVING STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTR(terms, 0, 10),'%d.%m.%Y') > NOW()`

Comment: But I can't use ORDER BY HAVING... can I?

Comment: NO :) HAVING is clause check this http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx You can try to use ith with WHERE but I am not sure if it will work You can use the expresion I wrote as alias and use where/having on this alias.

Answer (score 1):

If you order your result by date you have to put this:

```
 ORDER BY DATE(columnname) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with it

```
SELECT t.*, c.alias as calias FROM jos2_tabs t
    JOIN jos2_tabs_category c on c.id=t.category_id
    WHERE (category_id = 43
                OR category_id in (select id from jos2_tabs_category WHERE parentid = 43)
                ) AND state=1
```

And you will get all the rows without ordering then

```
foreach($rows as $key=>row)
{
    $my_date = explode('-',$row['terms']);
    $from = $my_date[0];
    $to = $my_date[1];
    $order_arr[$key] = strtotime($from);
}
array_multisort($order_arr, SORT_ASC, $rows);
print_r($rows);
```

You will get deserved

Comment: But I have got multiple from-to dates in one cell. And ordering by DATE(whole_cell) won't work :(

Comment: oh i didnt thought for that...but i think to store from to dates in one column is not the good idea at any cost

Comment: Yes. I know that this is not a good idea... but I didn't created this... My job is to modify this query and It is not that simple :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `select replace(terms,'.','-') from your_table WHERE 1` you will get `18.05.2013` to `18-05-2013`.

Now, you can change it go get your desired result.

Comment: And do You know how can I then order rows by first from date in each row?